# Java object value getting changed

Tags: java

I have an Object A. I assign values from A to Object B.  Object A is then changed, but I want to maintain the original values in Object B.

```
ObjectA a = getObjectAValues();

ObjectB b = new ObjectB();

b.setval(a.getValA());

//object A updated here

return b;
```

When I check the second object, it has the updated values, rather than the original value when I first assigned it.  Any ideas how to get past this?

Comment: Not a dupe - that explains the mechanics but doesn't actually *answer* the question.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve, nor what is problem with current code. When you say "Object A is then changed" do you mean value of `a` or `a.getValA()` (which also is confusing)?

Comment: Not really enough information here to answer your question.  What does each class look like?  What kind of changes are you making to `ObjectA`?

Answer (score 4):

Java is [pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/1079354), which means that if you pass in an instance of `ObjectA` into an object and later change some state about that object, it will be reflected wherever it was passed in, chiefly because the value of a reference is its location in memory.

How do you fix it?  *Copy* the value into your object so that you don't run the risk of it changing on you. This can be done quickly by `new`ing up an instance of `ObjectA` when assigning the value.

```
public void setval(ObjectA val) {
    this.val = new ObjectA(val.getField1(), val.getField2());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value you get from `a.getValA()` is an Object, it's passed by reference instead of by value. Meaning it's not a copy of the original, but the same object. When you modify it in A, you are also modifying it in B since it's just two references to the same object.

If you share a bit more of detail about how that Object is built, I can edit this to be more specific.